# Buildout custom Index ignored

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, buildout

I'm having an issue while setting up my environment with a custom `index` when installing `PasteScript`. Buildout attempts to install it from pypi while every other package is retrieved successfully from the custom `index`.

Below is the `buildout.cfg` I'm using:

```
[buildout]

index = http://10.10.10.10:8080/
include-site-packages = false
# allow-hosts = 10.10.10.10:8080/
newest = false
find-links = http://10.10.10.10:8080
install-from-cache = false

develop = 
... 

parts =
...
```

Relevant system packages:

```
$ pip list
setuptools (20.2.2)
zc.buildout (2.5.0)
...
```

#### Another paths

- Uncommenting `allow-hosts` didn't do any better. Buildout doesn't look for it. (Is this the way to configure `allow-hosts` with IPs???)
- Declaring `PasteDeploy` before `PasteScript` was futile as well. Buildout install PasteDeploy correctly in the eggs folder, however Buildout looks for `PasteScript` at `pypi` again.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some frustrating iterations on this issue I found a workaround. This situation arises depending on how the package's `setup.py` is configured as explained in [pip's docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#controlling-setup-requires).

In order to control how these dependencies are located by `easy_install`, you should override the package's `setup.py` configuration. This could be done at a "system" or "personal" level.

To override with user-wide ("personal") configuration create a file named `.pydistutils.cfg` at your `$HOME` with the following content:

```
[easy_install]
index_url = https://my-index.com
```

The complete documentation about `distutils` options is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#location-and-names-of-config-files).